# MinGW ís not working

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++, mingw

I installed the C++ compiler MinGW following [this tutorial](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/Cygwin_HowTo.html#mingw), but when i used the consol commands:

```
> gcc --version
g++ (GCC) 4.8.1
......

> g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.8.1
......

> gdb --version
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6.1
```

i dont receive any information and the console prints 'gcc is not recognizable as internal or external command'

Answer (score 1):

When you execute step 3:

> 3. Setup environment variable `PATH` to include `"<MINGW_HOME>/bin"` where `<MINGW_HOME>` is the MinGW installed directory that you have chosen in the previous step.

Be aware that changes made to your path in the control panel don't affect *existing* consoles.

You need to open up a *new* console for the path to affect it.

The other possibility is that you've modified the path in a console you were working in but this is the wrong way to do it, since that path will not affect future consoles.

Comment: i added the MinGW path to the system path. what do u mean by 'your path in the control panel don't affect existing consoles'

Comment: @user2121: I mean that, assuming you did the right thing and modified path via the control panel, that will only affect _future_ consoles (think of `cmd `windows). If you have a console already open, that doesn't get the new path - you need to exit it and run another one. Just ensure `echo %path%` has the correct directory in it.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely missed this step:

> Setup environment variable PATH to include `"<MINGW_HOME>/bin"` where `<MINGW_HOME>` is the MinGW installed directory that you have chosen in the previous step.

What is the output of this command?

> echo $PATH

If it does not include `"<MINGW_HOME>/bin"`, you need to make the necessary adjustment.

Besides, that tutorial is somewhat dated. [Cygwin Ports](https://sourceware.org/cygwinports/) does *include* packages for MinGW, plus precompiled libraries, available from Cygwin's setup.exe. The packages are:

- mingw64-i686-gcc
- mingw64-i686-gcc-g++

or

- mingw64-x86-gcc
- mingw64-x86-gcc-g++

depending on your architecture. If you use those packages, the compiler will be installed in `/usr/bin` (which already is in your `PATH`), and you can access it (e.g. as `i686-w64-mingw32-gcc`) right away.

Comment: @user2121: Unix is case-sensitive. It's `echo $PATH`. And if your output is really and literally "path", I suggest you take a tutorial on Unix command line and environment variables first. ;-)

Comment: `%path%`, I think you'll find, for Windows.

Comment: @paxdiablo: The tutorial is about a Cygwin setup, so he's working on a bash.